# how do you create an event listener to listen for click and enter key at the same time?

Tags: javascript, methods, click, event-listener, keydown

how do you create an event listener to listen for click and enter key at the same time with little code? Is there a short method for this? In a perfect world i would imagine something like addEventListner('click', 'keyDown-enter'){}

Comment: You forgot to include the example code

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be using two flag variables to check if the user has clicked and pressed enter key at the same time, and setTimeout to remove the flags.

```js
var flagClick = false;
var flagEnter = false;
var element = document.body // You must specify element here.

element.addEventListener('click', e => {
    flagClick = true;
    setTimeout(()=>{flagClick=false},100);
    if(flagEnter){
        trigger();
    }
});
element.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    if(e.key == 'Enter') {
        flagEnter = true;
        setTimeout(()=>{flagEnter=false},100);
        if(flagClick){
            trigger();
        }
    }
});

function trigger(){
  // your code
}
```

Hope it helps.